# dnx project start up error - dnx design time process. No connection could be made

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx

When I open a (dnx46) project in my visual studio I (most of the times) get the following error:

> The following error occurred attempting to run the DNX design time process (dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final)
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:39084
>
> The DNX design time process provides intellisense, build and reference information to Visual Studio and without it your experience will be very limited. Please tyr closing and reopening Visual Studio to see if that corrects the problem. Alternatively, check that the DNX version is properly installed or try changing to a different installed DNX version using the project property pages.

I started getting this error last week. I have the problem with all my dnx prjects, including the one's that haven't changed since then.

My dnx is RC1-final. I tried installing RC1-update1 but to no avail.

Restarting the visual studio sometimes helps but not very often.

The problems with not having this design time process are:

- no 'web' profile to debug (or any other option to debug)
- references are not visible in visual studio
- Building takes a huge huge amount of time

Is there anyone that has any idea what is going on and what I can do to it?

Comment: I ended up clearing my system. I also had a problem with two separate versions of visual studio 2015 that made it impossible to update them...

Comment: Do you have another VS 2015 process running?  If I accidentally open two instances at the same time I get this error.

Comment: I tried this with nothing open except for the visual studio. I experienced this problem many times and ended up reinstalling the entire system. For now, everything is working fine with all my projects.

Comment: reinstalling vs2015 didn't help? i'm having same problem, so if u have any suggestion how to fix it (rather than reinstalling whole system), please tell me

Comment: I somehow had two versions installed of VS 2015 (professional and Enterprise). Upgrading, Re-installing or de-installing did more bad than good so I ended up cleaning the entire system.

Comment: Reinstall the entire system is the solution... So microsoft!!!

Answer (score 5):

Well, executing dnvm update-self command before opening the project does the job for me as mentioned here.

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-fix-dnx-project-start-up-error-in-vs-2015/

Comment: With the link, you should try to give a bit explanation as well.

Comment: Links might become outdated, deleted or obsolete. Please consider giving some explanation yourself as well.

Comment: Well, running the dnvm update-self command for now does fix this issue but this is a temporary solution. I guess there is some problem with the VS setup but nothing concrete though.

Comment: I tried this solution. It didn't do the trick for me but I guess it's a good reference for people having this same error message and landing here...

Comment: I think you are right. It's working sometime for me but not all the time. What I am doing is if dnvm update-self doesn't work, then I try dnvm upgrade command and that works. This is a very weird issue and quite frustrating. Microsoft must address this ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Repairing the ASP.NET 5 Release Candidate solved it for me, at least so far.  I've been been running a day or so.  Get the latest install here which also performs the repair: https://get.asp.net/

Comment: This didn't work for me at the time but i didn't use the installer you are referring to. It also seems like a sensible thing to do when having this problem. If more people confirm this answer as a solution to the problem I am willing to accept this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run VS: Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console:

- dnvm upgrade
- dnvm upgrade -r CoreClr

Comment: It worked for me but I had to run this commands in the project folder at `Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject`

Answer (score 0):

i get the same error what i did was erease the .dxn folder in my user acound 
C:\Users\usr.dnx

Answer (score 0):

Swapping dot net versions seemed to help

```
dnvm list
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r coreclr
```

Presumably change and change back could work, I'll report back if I get to test this again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Run the command: 
`dnvm upgrade`.
And then change the DNX version in the properties of the project to 1.0.0-rc1-update2 (or another new version):
[image: Properties of the project]

Answer (score 0):

I am running `1.0.0-rc1-update1` , the following command line worked.

```
dnvm update-self
```

Then close and reopen the solution in visual studio. Error no longer show up. `dnvm list` shows I am still running the same version.